# How to extract file name from random image <img> tags in Open Office

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have about 1500 items in an Open Office CSV file like this:

```
<a href=\http://localhost:81/rare_posts/?attachment_id=9044\"><img class=\"alignright size-medium wp-image-9044\" title=\"200064 British medical association\" src=\"http://localhost:81/books_posts/wp-content/uploads/British-medical-association-300x202.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"300\" height=\"202\" /></a>
```

What I need to do is find just the image (British-medical-association-300x202.jpg) and place this into the next cell. I am assuming there must be some way for me to run a command in Open Office to find all instances of **uploads/**, the point where we start stripping out all the text after this point and stop at **.jpg**?

Many thanks!

Comment: Parsing the text should be fairly easy with a regex

Comment: `src=\".*uploads\/([^"]+\.jpg)\"`

Comment: Hi Jan. I've done a bit of reading now and not quite understanding how I can use this? I would assume that I need to run this RegEx on the cell next to cell I am trying to strip the image filename FROM, right?

Comment: It seems that OpenOffice has no "match a regex and return the match" function. I should have noticed sooner. I'll write an answer.

Comment: I'm busy going through this documentation http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc, just trying figure out how to use your example in one of the options they give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenOffice has no formula function to return a match by a regex. It does support regex search if you enable regular expressions in the options.

You can go with two formulas to extract one occurence per cell (without using a regex search). One to find the left end and one to find the right end:

Assuming the data is in A1

```
B1   =MID(A1;FIND("uploads/";A1)+8;LEN(A1))
C1   =LEFT(B1;FIND("\";B1)-1)
```

If you have more than one occurence per cell, you can clone the formulas and supply the first `FIND` a third parameter, where to start searching (past the first occurence).

Comment: So far that forumala is working a charm, thanks Jan! Going to try work out your second suggestion now about the FIND option.

Comment: You just saved me HOURS of work! They should have a donate button on Stack, so people can make some money from their answers.